# How to add radio button using selectedType with one radio button disabbled in code.js

Tags: google-apps-script

wanted to create a two radio button using SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON with one radio button is disabled..

```
section.addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON).setFieldName("type").setTitle("")
      .addItem('Matter',1,true).addItem('Intake',2,false).setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("radioButtonSelection")));
```

Comment: Welcome. Please add more details and a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. By the way, are you developing a Gmail add-on?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation about the addItem() function [1], doesn't show any way to add the "disabled" attribute to the radio button. A workaround would be to serve an HTML where you can code that, but Gmail Add-ons has the restriction that you can only use the CardService class to build the add-on [2][3].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input#addItem(Object,Object,Boolean)

[2] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/restrictions

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service